# AWS Amplify many-to-many - delete not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, many-to-many, aws-amplify

I have a many-to-many relationship in amplify with the following schema

```
type Blog 
@model 
@searchable 
{
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  tags: [BlogTag] @connection(keyName: "byBlog", fields: ["id"])
}

type Tag 
@model 
@searchable
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  blogs: [BlogTag] @connection(keyName: "byTag", fields: ["id"])
}

type BlogTag 
@model 
@key(name: "byBlog", fields: ["blogID", "tagID"]) 
@key(name: "byTag", fields: ["tagID", "blogID"]) 
{
  id: ID!
  blogID: ID!
  tagID: ID!
  blog: Blog! @connection(fields: ["blogID"])
  tag: Tag! @connection(fields: ["tagID"])
}
```

And when I try to delete a BlogTag entry, I get the following error:

```
message: "Conflict resolver rejects mutation."
path: ["deleteBlogTag"]
```

I try to delete the entry with the following code:

```
import { API } from "aws-amplify";
import {deleteBlogTag} from "../graphql/mutations";

...
await API.graphql({
      query: deleteBlogTag,
      variables: { input: { id: blogTagId } },
    });
```

I don't understand why there would be a conflict. If I were deleting a blog, and there'd be BlogTags pointing to that blog, then of course that's a conflict. But why is it a conflict deleting a BlogTag? Is it something I am missing in the schema?

Comment: deleting some entry in Blog.tags or in Tag.blogs should result in deleting 'connecting entry' (BlogTag) ... deleting 'connecting entry' leaves both connected sides with ids (tags or blogs entries) pointing to nowhere?

Comment: I tried that. But I can't update the Tags in the Blog directly or viceversa. I get the error "The variables input contains a field name 'tags' that is not defined for input object type 'UpdateBlogInput' " According to the docs, i have to delete the BlogTag entry...

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide _version parameter, i.e

```
await API.graphql({
      query: deleteBlogTag,
      variables: { input: { id: blogTagId, _version: version } },
      });
```

But I would suggest to go through `amplify update api` and remove sync conflict resolution.